# Find files and insert file modification date

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find, stat

I would like to append a line including date of file modification (preferably just the year) to all .m files.

To append variable text to all .sh files:
`find . -name "*.m" -exec sed -i '$a \\n# File last modified in '"$date"'' {} \;`

Could I get the year for each file and insert it into the file contents in the same line?

Comment: Do you have GNU find and GNU awk (use `find --version` and `awk --version` if you aren't sure)?

Comment: Yes, I have them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `find` one-liner might be what you want:

```
find -name '*.sh' -exec bash -c 'printf "# %(%Y)T\n" $(stat -c %Y "$1") >> "$1"' _ {} \;
```

assuming you have `stat` from GNU coreutils.

**A few notes:**
The `bash` syntax to execute a command string is `bash -c command_string arg_0 arg_1 ... arg_n` (args are optional). `arg_0` corresponds to bash special parameter `$0`, `arg_1` corresponds to bash special parameter `$1`, and so on, within the command string. For each file the `find` finds, the `{}` is replaced with the pathname and the bash command is executed. The string `_` is assigned to `$0` (it normally stands for the name of the shell or shell script, which doesn't interest us here because we're running a command string, not a file), and the pathname is assigned to the `$1`, then the command `printf "# %(%Y)T\n" $(stat -c %Y "$1") >> "$1"` is executed. `stat -c %Y` prints out the time of last data modification as seconds since Epoch and the format specification `%(%Y)T` in `printf` builtin of `bash` interprets this value as a year.

Comment: Perfect!! Could you please expand a little on the logic?

Comment: Neat, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU find and GNU awk and assuming you don't have newlines or leading/trailing white space in your file names

```
while read -r year file; do
    awk -i inplace -v year="$year" '{print} ENDFILE{print "#", year}' "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.sh' -printf '%TY %p\n')
```

You could do it more efficiently with just a pipe from find to awk and then modifying ARGV[] to create the file list, and you could make it able to handle newlines in  the names but it's more code and I'm too lazy.

Comment: Handling newlines in filenames doesn't require much work: Replace the `\n` with `\0` and add the `-d ''` option to the `read` command (assuming `bash`). Also, I cannot see a problem with backslashes in names.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin there's more awk changes required too but as mentioned I'm just being lazy. Regarding backslashes - right, it's leading/trailing white space that;s the issue if I don't set `IFS=''`.

Comment: Leading whitespace is not possible because pathnames printed out will begin with `./` in your `find` command. Trailing one also is impossible since the `find` command searches filenames ending with `.sh`. So no need to mess up with the `IFS`.